# Memory issue with Variables

Tags: c#, memory-management

I have read a lot about memory management but there is still some things I cannot grasp at the moment.  This may look awkward but is this code below has

1. performance issues
2. Memory wastage

This function "Bitmap b=Iprocessing.Colour_style(Bitmap a)" takes gray scale image a and gives it color and return a colored image b

I have been going with the idea that since the `new` key word has not been used, the variable `images[1]` after processing will replace the old content and no new memory is created.

please enlighten me

```
  for(int i=0; i<images.Count;i++)   {   
    images[i] = Iprocessing.Colour_style((Bitmap)images[i]);
  }
```

Comment: What does `Iprocessing.Colour_style` do ?

Comment: Just by the way, your `for` loop has an off-by-one error in its condition. Use `i < images.Count`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that typo out, it was not like that in the code

Comment: @Habib, I have edited my question by stating the function of Iprocessing.Colour_style in the question. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: If the code for `Iprocessing.Colour_style` is small, you could also post it...

Comment: For memory/performance issues, don't *guess* at where these might occur. If you need to know, use a profiler to locate the hot spots.

Answer (score 0):

The *variables* here are `i` and `images` (and even the `images` I can't be sure about without seeing the declaration - it could be a field). `images` here is just a reference to (it looks like) a `List<Image>` - so the entire of `images` is either 4 or 8 bytes. The list itself will take more space; there is the object itself, plus the backing array, plus a few counters. Swapping an item in a list, as with swapping an element in an array, does not involve allocating any extra room in the list/array.

The one thing that *could* (and almost certainly *does*) cause allocation here is the `IProcessing.Color_style`. It *sounds* like this will be creating a new image based on an old image (rather than changing the old image in place). Furthermore, it *looks* a lot like you aren't disposing the old image - so if this is the *only* place you are using that image, you could be causing yourself a few problems: images are `IDisposable` and are linked to GDI+ handles; if you don't dispose them you can get problems with `OutOfMemoryException` that isn't linked to *memory*, but actually to GDI+ handles. Especially if you have a lot of spare memory, so that garbage collection doesn't happen very frequently. Of course, this is also slightly complicated because if you *are* using that image elsewhere (on a control, etc), then you ***do not*** want to dispose it now!

A line does not need to involve `new` to involve an allocation (allocations can be hidden behind method-calls, operators, properties); likewise, not every line involving `new` requires an allocation (value-types are initialized over the top of the existing location).